# How to run an awk command on file in emacs

Tags: shell, emacs, awk

If I am visiting a file in emacs I want to be able to run a simple awk command, eg

```
awk /Sam/ { print $0 }.
```

How would I construct this.

I tried:

```
m-! - to be able to run a shell cmd

awk '/Sam/ { print $0 }' test.txt
```

But then I get this error:

```
awk: c:/MinGW/msys/1.0/Sam/ { print }
awk:  ^ syntax error
awk: c:/MinGW/msys/1.0/Sam/ { print }
awk:                        ^ syntax error
errcount: 2
```

Running just awk '{ print }' test.txt works

I am running on Windows 7 using minGW and my shell is set to:

```
echo %SHELL%
C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/bash.exe
```

How do I escape the /Sam/ ?  It thinks it is part of the directory to the exe I think?  I tried (trying gawk to see if get better diagnotic msg):

```
gawk '\/Sam\/ { print $0 }' test.txt

gawk: cmd. line:1: \/Sam\/ { print }
gawk: cmd. line:1: ^ backslash not last character on line
```

test.txt file contains:

```
Angus
Lisa
Samuel
Annabel
Jack
Wookie
```

Comment: You need to quote the expression in awk. Try like this: `awk '/^ABC/ { print $0 }' test.txt`

Comment: @user000001 I tried both " and ' as per your way above but still get No such file or directory

Comment: does this file exists in the current path, just guessing?

Comment: @user000001 awk '{ print }' test.txt works.  But I am having problems escaping the funny characters eg /

Comment: Are you trying to run `awk` on the file contents or the file name? If you want to invoke `awk` on file's name, why not open `dired` buffer and then use `M-!` from there? (better yet, if you have `dired-x` enabled use `dired-jump`). But if you want to run `awk` on the contents of the buffer, maybe you need `M-|` instead?

Comment: For example, if I wanted to run `awk` on the contents of the current file, I'd do: `M-x dired-jump` `M-!` `awk '/#\+/ { print $0 }' ?` would give me all the Org macro usages in the current file.

Comment: Actually you can work around this with just `awk /Sam/` since `{ print $0 }` is the default action anyway. But more generally, I believe quoting rules on Windows are different -- try double quotes (or a real OS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was related to my environment.  I am running on Windows and using MSYS with fairly old, some from 1998, versions of awk, etc.

For anyone else who has a similar problem you might consider removing use of msys and using the gnu utilities from this link:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/

Answer (score 1):

This is how to escape `/Sam/`, you need a `\` before the `/`. PS you do not need `{print $0}`, its the default action in `awk`.

```
echo "/Sam/" | awk '/\/Sam\//'
/Sam/
```

Comment: I am looking for the text Sam - I don't need to look for raw text /Sam/ (not sure if you realised that)..  Using your cmd literally as in echo "/Sam/" | awk '/\/Sam//' test.txt - I get awk: ///Sam// awk: unexpected newline or end of string

Comment: It would then be nice if you post your data file and how you like the output to be. If you just are looking for all lines with `Sam` in it, then `awk 'Sam' test.txt`

Comment: Sorry I tried that but then get no output.  see msg Shell command succeeded with no output. Input file now in question.  I realise I could use grep but want to be able to use awk two in this way.

Comment: My fault, I meant `awk '/Sam/' test.txt` if that does not work it have to windows related, sine this is basic function and works fine in several linux version. This should work in Windows gawk

Comment: OK it must be a Windows/minGW issue then.  Using that I get awk: cmd. line:1: c:\MinGW/msys/1.0/Sam/ - unexpected newline or end of string (poinys to just after last / after Sam  I tried single and double quotes.